# how to map the data obtained from business events to json object

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I have customized the business events from D365 and the data that is fetched from business events needs to be composed into a json array.

I parsed the json from business events and I am trying to compose the json array to send it to third party service.

I have the output from the parse json step as follows

```
{
  "body": {
    "BillClientId": "abcdef",
    "BillRad": "Request",
    "Boxes": 0,
    "BusinessEventId": "SBSalesInvoicePostingBusinessEvents",
    "BusinessEventLegalEntity": "usmf",
    "comt": "",
    "ContextRecordSubject": "",
    "ControlNumber": 123456,
    "CustAccount": "",
    "Description": "",
    "DestAddressType": "DESTINATION",
    "Destcity3": "San Diego",
    "Destcity4": "San Diego",
    "DestclntName": "Contoso Retail Los Angeles",
    "Destcontacto": "Contoso Retail San Diego",
    "DestCountry": "USA",
    "Destdoor": "S/N",
    "Destemail": "contoso.retail.los.angeles@customer62.consolidatedmessenger.com",
    "Destphone": "123-444-555"
  }
}
```

I am trying to compose the data in the format as shown in the image, I am trying to assign the values from previous parse json step into compose, but I am unable to get the expected output as the values are not being fetched. the output comes up with no data, can anyone please let me know is there a way to achieve it or am I making any mistake.

{
"body": {
"request": {
"data": [
{
"billClntId": " @{body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['BillClientId']}",
"billRad": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['BillRad']}",
"comt": "",
"listRefs": [
{

I believe I am trying to add the properties how can I add the values

Comment: You really need to complete the JSON definition at the bottom.  It's vastly incomplete.  Also, why do you have the `['properties']` part in the expression?  That doesn't exist in the provided JSON.

Comment: I have just provided the bit of it I haven't provided the entire json

Comment: What I am trying to do is I have a specific json format in which I am trying to send the data to third party so I am trying to assign the values coming from the parse json step.

Comment: In the sense I am using the dynamic contents and assigning them to the specific areas in the compose step

Comment: What exactly I am trying to do is I am trying to assign the value from a dynamic content to the json object

Comment: I get that but put simply, `['properties']` doesn't exist in the JSON so remove that and try again.

Comment: I tried it worked and value was fetched but when i go to create next expression
the old one is still appearing and getting updated it is not allowing me to create a new expression

Comment: Sorry, too hard to help without additional screenshots.

Comment: Hi I can u please help me to upload the screenshots it is not allowing me I dont know why

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand. How are you creating new expression and how the expression looks like? Without details, not able to proceed.
Try to clear cache and upload screen shots.
If you are still unable to upload image, provide Json and expression how you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Skin thanks for leading into right direction making it as a solution to help others also.

Issue reproduced from my end got expected results by following below steps.

- As Shown below is the workflow of logic App I have taken.
  [image]

  Taken When a http request is received trigger to retrive data as you mentioned.
  [image]

```
{

"properties": {

"body": {

"properties": {

"BillClientId": {

"type": "string"

},

"BillRad": {

"type": "string"

},

"Boxes": {

"type": "integer"

},

"BusinessEventId": {

"type": "string"

},

"BusinessEventLegalEntity": {

"type": "string"

},

"ContextRecordSubject": {

"type": "string"

},

"ControlNumber": {

"type": "integer"

},

"CustAccount": {

"type": "string"

},

"Description": {

"type": "string"

},

"DestAddressType": {

"type": "string"

},

"DestCountry": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destcity3": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destcity4": {

"type": "string"

},

"DestclntName": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destcontacto": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destdoor": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destemail": {

"type": "string"

},

"Destphone": {

"type": "string"

},

"comt": {

"type": "string"

}

},

"type": "object"

}

},

"type": "object"

}
```

Then taken parse Json action and  In the "Content" field, set the "Body" parameter of the trigger output and  In the "Schema" field take the JSON schema.
[image]

- Add Compose action and take input as shown in below image to get desired output.
  [image]
- Logic App ran successfully and below is the expected output of compose action.
  [image]
  [image]

output of compose

```
{

"body": {

"request": {

"data": [

{

"billClntId": "abcdef",

"billRad": "Request",

"comt": "",

"listRefs": [

{}

]

}

]

}

}

}
```

Note: when coming to next expression you need to edit the question properly for that.